# I want to connect YII framework with two databases but it throws CDbConnection failed Incorrect database name

Tags: php, mysql, database, yii, yii1.x

I have used [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/78/multiple-databases-and-multiple-domains/#hh0) tutorial to connect YII with two database

I have added a connection string in the 
`protected/config/main.php`
which is as follows

```
'db2'=>array(
            'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=db_name ',
            'emulatePrepare' => true,
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'class' => 'CDbConnection'
    ),
```

I have created a file under

`protected/component/AltActiveRecord.php` 
a class file and the code in this file is

`

```
abstract class AltActiveRecord extends CActiveRecord
    {
        const BELONGS_TO='CBelongsToRelation';
        const HAS_ONE='CHasOneRelation';
        const HAS_MANY='CHasManyRelation';
        const MANY_MANY='CManyManyRelation';
        const STAT='CStatRelation';     
        public static $db2;

        private static $_models=array();            

        private $_md;                               
        private $_new=false;                        

        private $_attributes=array();               

        private $_related=array();                  

        private $_c;                                

        private $_pk;                               

        public function getDbConnection()
        {
            if(self::$db2!==null)
                return self::$db2;
            else
            {


                self::$db2 = new CDbConnection();
                foreach(Yii::app()->db2 as $key => $value)
                    self::$db2->$key = $value;



                if(self::$db2 instanceof CDbConnection)
                {
                self::$db2->setActive(true);
                return self::$db2;
            }
            else
                throw new CDbException(Yii::t('yii','Active Record requires a "db" CDbConnection application component.'));
            }
            }
            }
`
```

I have created a model which extends to this class and tried to create the object of this model in controller.
but it ends with an error, which says

`CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1102] Incorrect database name "db_name"`

I am wondering why this is not working.
Is it related to php version or yii version

Comment: double check your database name.

Comment: you can use self::$db2 = Yii::app()->db2

Comment: @InsaneSkull I have checked it again and again

Comment: There is no 'db_name' in the code you provided. Is the source code and the error messages exactly you pasted how your have in on your system.

Comment: Please Look from some distance... because the closer you look the less you see. It's there.

Answer (score 0):

On your connection string, there is an extra space at the end of the line (after `db_name`):

```
'db2'=>array(
            'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=db_name ',
            'emulatePrepare' => true,
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'class' => 'CDbConnection'
    ),
```

should be:

```
'db2'=>array(
            'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=db_name',
            'emulatePrepare' => true,
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'class' => 'CDbConnection'
    ),
```